# `input_data': undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

Hello guys I have the following problem:

**INPUT**:
2
ababaa
aa

**OUTPUT**:
11
3

**Explanation:**
For the first case, the suffixes of the string are "ababaa", "babaa", "abaa", "baa", "aa" and "a". The similarities of each of these strings with the string "ababaa" are 6,0,3,0,1,1 respectively. Thus the answer is 6 + 0 + 3 + 0 + 1 + 1 = 11.

For the second case, the answer is 2 + 1 = 3.

This part works , but some of the test that my code should pass don't.

Here is my code

```
def input_data
#STDIN.flush
tries = gets.chomp
end

strings=[];
tries = input_data until (tries =~ /^[1-9]$/)
tries = tries.to_i
strings << input_data until (strings.count == tries)

strings.map do |x|
values = 0
current = x.chars.to_a
(0..x.length-1).map do |possition| 
    current_suffix = x[possition..-1].chars.to_a
    (0..current_suffix.length-1).map do |number|
        if (current_suffix[0] != current[0])
            break
        end

        if ( current_suffix[number] == current[number] )
            values = values+1
        end
    end 
  end

  if (values != 0)
    puts values
  end
end
```

Any suggestions how to fix it ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`gets` returns `nil`, which cannot be `chomp`ed. Therefore, you need to make sure, that you work on an actual string before calling `chomp`. A common idiom in ruby is to use the `||=` operator to set a variable only if it is nil. So you would write:

```
tries = gets        # get input
tries ||= ''        # set to empty string if nil
tries.chomp!        # remove trailing newline
```